# Spring Security with SSO

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

we are working on spring boot with spring security and oauth2.Now we need to change our security to use SSO.We have an external server that provide SSO service for us by JWT(An Oracle product).My question is how we can do that with spring security?

Comment: what is your external sever, it it a separate service ? how are you going to communicate with this ?

Comment: yes it is a separate service (a product from ORACLE).It has a endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a reverse proxy.

You can use Netflix Zuul edge service library which itself will be a separate spring boot application. All requests to your main application will pass through proxy server from where you can call your SSO provider and validate your request.

Read this [Link](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul)